# Looping ggplot over subsets of data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to generate plots using a loop. The script will need to be flexible enough to generate a variable number of plots, depending on the input data. I've set up a loop for this to run through each data based on the unique values in the 'FOV' column as shown below; however, the plots generated keep using the same bit of data so all plots are identical (e.g. not using different subsets of the dataframe based on values in FOV). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    #Getting all FOVs to loop  
    FOV_list <- unique(df_cl$FOV)

    #Create a list to store the ClEff plot  
    ClEff_plots = list()

    #looping over unique FOV names  
    for (FOV in FOV_list) {  

    ClEff_plots[[FOV]] = ggplot(df_cl %>% filter(FOV == FOV), aes(x=ID)) +   
        geom_point(aes(y=BB_ClEff, col="BB_ClEff"),size=0.1) + 
        geom_point(aes(y=GG_ClEff, col="GG_ClEff"),size=0.1) +   
        geom_point(aes(y=YY_ClEff, col="YY_ClEff"),size=0.1) +   
        geom_point(aes(y=RR_ClEff, col="RR_ClEff"),size=0.1) + 
        labs(title="ClEff",   
             y="Cleave %", x="Cycle") +    
        theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) + 
        theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
        #theme(panel.border = element_rect()) + 
        facet_wrap(df_cl$Cycle, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +  
        scale_color_manual(name="",   
                   values = c("BB_ClEff"="#0072B2", "GG_ClEff"="#009E73", "YY_ClEff"="#F0E442", "RR_ClEff"="#D55E00")) +   
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

    print(ClEff_plots[[FOV]])

    ggsave(ClEff_plots[[FOV]], file=paste0('ClEff_plot_FOV_', FOV, '.png'),
     width = 44.45, height = 27.78, units = 'cm', dpi = 600, path = "~/desktop/Outputs/")

    }
```

Comment: You already have a column called `FOV` in your data, so it would be sensible to call the iterator something different like `i`. It looks as though `filter` is getting confused about what you mean when you write `filter(FOV == FOV)`. You are expecting R to know that one of these refers to the iterator variable and one to the column, but how can it?

Comment: @AllanCameron I started off with 'i' instead of 'FOV' however I get this error when 'i' is used: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 768 rows, data has 128

Comment: Try `filter(FOV == !!FOV)`

Comment: @Arthur - That returns the same error as i: Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : replacement has 768 rows, data has 128

Comment: The error may be coming from `facet_wrap`, where you are trying to facet on the whole dataframe worth of data. Try the formula notation `facet_wrap(.~Cycle, ...)`

Comment: Ah that did it! Fixing the facet_wrap() formula has it working using 'i' or filter(FOV == !!FOV) Thank you both!